# These Primes of Mine Are Always Solid Lines

Tags: code-golf, primes

Let's create a N×N grid of spaces and underscores that can be used to visually determine if a number is prime. (N may be any positive integer.)

This grid has three simple rules:

1. The nth column contains the repeated pattern of n - 1 underscores followed by one space. This pattern starts at the first row and is stopped, possibly mid-pattern, at row N. (Rows and columns are 1-indexed.)
2. The first column is replaced with all underscores instead of all spaces.
3. If a space occurs somewhere the row index equals the column index it is replaced with an underscore.

## Example: N = 10

```
           1
  1234567890 <-- column indices
 1__________
 2__________
 3__________
 4_ ________
 5__________
 6_  _______
 7__________
 8_ _ ______
 9__ _______
10_ __ _____
 ^ row indices
```

The indices are just for clarity. The plain grid itself (what your program must output) is:

```
__________
__________
__________
_ ________
__________
_  _______
__________
_ _ ______
__ _______
_ __ _____
```

Notice that:

- The first column is all underscores.
- The second column goes underscore space, underscore space, etc., except for the underscore on row 2.
- The third column goes underscore underscore space, underscore underscore space, etc., except for the underscore on row 3.
- etc.

**Also notice that besides 1, only prime numbered rows have underscores in every column.**

Since underscores span the entire font width, each prime numbered row forms a continuous solid line. So checking if a number is prime or not is quite easy visually; just check if its line is solid across all columns. (In fact looking up to the square root of the row index suffices but outputting that grid seems less elegant.)

## Program

Write a program that will draw these grids given N via stdin (or closest alternative). Output goes to stdout (or closest alternative) and should only contain spaces, underscores, and newlines, with an optional trailing newline.

The shortest code wins.

Comment: I don't get how does it determine prime number

Comment: @FilipBartuzi Maybe check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: "The nth column contains the repeated pattern of n - 1 underscores followed by one space." So shouldn't column n=1 be all spaces, not all underscores?

Comment: @algorithmshark Fixed

Comment: It's a good thing those indices don't need to be printed. Was starting to remind me of the punch card one

Comment: I must say I don't particularly like the "no trailing newline" requirement. This is very difficult in some languages, downright impossible in others and it only affects programs that print to STDOUT.

Comment: @Dennis Really? Why would it be impossible? I've allowed a trailing newline anyway since its presence has little to do with the challenge.

Comment: Some languages have limited input/output format since they're not made for "programs" in the usual sense. I'm thinking about Mathematica, Octave, etc. I believe J is one of those languages too, but I'm not actually sure. -- Thanks for changing the requirement. I had to either ask you or leave a comment under every other answer...

Comment: The description was hard for me to understand. This is how I would describe it: Start with a grid of N lines of N underscores. For the `n`th line, make the `k`th character a space if `k` is a divisor of `m` that isn't 1 or `m`.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>33</s> <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
q~,:)_f{f{md\1=+'_S?}0'_tN}
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### How it works

```
q~        " Read one line from STDIN and evaluate it.                                     ";
,:)       " For “N”, push [ 1 ... N ].                                                    ";
_         " Push a copy.                                                                  ";
f{        " For each “I in [ 1 ... N ], push “I   [ 1 ... N ]”; then:                     ";
  f{      " For each “J in [ 1 ... N ], push “J   I”; then:                               ";
    md\   " Push “J % I   J / I”.                                                         ";
    1=+   " Calculate “J % I + (J / I == 1)”.                                             ";
    '_S?  " Push an underscore if the result is truthy and a space otherwise.             ";
  }       "                                                                               ";
  0'_t    " Replace the first character of the resulting array by an underscore.          ";
  N       " Push a newline.                                                               ";
}         "                                                                               ";
```

#### Example run

```
$ cjam solid-primes.cjam <<< 10
__________
__________
__________
_ ________
__________
_  _______
__________
_ _ ______
__ _______
_ __ _____
$ cjam solid-primes.cjam <<< 100 | md5sum # trailing newline
e4396b316989813dada21141b569ccf9  -
```

Comment: I'll post an explanation when I'm done golfing.

Comment: 33 bytes and you're not done golfing??

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>77</s> 73 characters

```
puts (1..n=gets.to_i).map{|a|?_+(2..n).map{|b|a!=b&&a%b==0? ' ':?_}.join}
```

Some tricks I used:

- The `..` operator has almost the lowest precedence of all operators in Ruby, so `(1..n=gets.to_i)` just works.
- Instead of adding an extra `a!=1` condition when checking to see if the character should be a space instead of an underscore (since the first row is all underscores), I just started the range from `2` and prepended an extra `?_`.
- Line A can become line B:

  ```
  A | a%b==0&&a!=b ? ' ':?_
  B | a!=b&&a%b==0? ' ':?_
  ```

  because I have to have an extra space between `b` and `?` in line A, but that's not needed between `0` and `?` in line B. `b?` is a valid Ruby method, but `0?` is not.
- `puts` will automatically join arrays with newlines for you, removing the need for an extra `*"\n"`.

Output for `n=100`:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ __________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_  _________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ _ ________________________________________________________________________________________________
__ _________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ __ _______________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_   _ ______________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ ____ _____________________________________________________________________________________________
__ _ _______________________________________________________________________________________________
_ _ ___ ____________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_  __ __ ___________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ _  ____ __________________________________________________________________________________________
__ ___ _____________________________________________________________________________________________
_ ________ _________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_   _ _ ___ ________________________________________________________________________________________
____ _______________________________________________________________________________________________
_ __________ _______________________________________________________________________________________
__ _____ ___________________________________________________________________________________________
_ _ __ ______ ______________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_  _  ___ ____ _____________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ _ ___ _______ ____________________________________________________________________________________
__ _______ _________________________________________________________________________________________
_ ______________ ___________________________________________________________________________________
____ _ _____________________________________________________________________________________________
_   _ __ __ _____ __________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ ________________ _________________________________________________________________________________
__ _________ _______________________________________________________________________________________
_ _  __ _ _________ ________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_  __  ______ ______ _______________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ _ ______ __________ ______________________________________________________________________________
__ _ ___ _____ _____________________________________________________________________________________
_ ____________________ _____________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_   _ _ ___ ___ _______ ____________________________________________________________________________
______ _____________________________________________________________________________________________
_ __ ____ ______________ ___________________________________________________________________________
__ _____________ ___________________________________________________________________________________
_ _ ________ ____________ __________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_  __ __ ________ ________ _________________________________________________________________________
____ _____ _________________________________________________________________________________________
_ _ __  _____ _____________ ________________________________________________________________________
__ _______________ _________________________________________________________________________________
_ __________________________ _______________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_     ___ _ __ ____ _________ ______________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ ____________________________ _____________________________________________________________________
__ ___ _ ___________ _______________________________________________________________________________
_ _ ___ _______ _______________ ____________________________________________________________________
____ _______ _______________________________________________________________________________________
_  __ ____ __________ __________ ___________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ _ ____________ ________________ __________________________________________________________________
__ ___________________ _____________________________________________________________________________
_ __ _ __ ___ ____________________ _________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_   _ _  __ _____ _____ ___________ ________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ __________________________________ _______________________________________________________________
__ _ _________ _________ ___________________________________________________________________________
_ _ ______________ __________________ ______________________________________________________________
______ ___ _________________________________________________________________________________________
_  __ ______ ____________ ____________ _____________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ _  __ _ _____ ___ ___________________ ____________________________________________________________
__ _____ _________________ _________________________________________________________________________
_ ______________________________________ ___________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_   _  ____ _ ______ ______ _____________ __________________________________________________________
____ ___________ ___________________________________________________________________________________
_ ________________________________________ _________________________________________________________
__ _________________________ _______________________________________________________________________
_ _ ___ __ __________ _____________________ ________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_  _  __  ____ __ ___________ ______________ _______________________________________________________
______ _____ _______________________________________________________________________________________
_ _ __________________ ______________________ ______________________________________________________
__ ___________________________ _____________________________________________________________________
_ ____________________________________________ _____________________________________________________
____ _____________ _________________________________________________________________________________
_   _ _ ___ ___ _______ _______ _______________ ____________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_ ____ ______ __________________________________ ___________________________________________________
__ _____ _ _____________________ ___________________________________________________________________
_ _  ____ _________ ____ ________________________ __________________________________________________
```

Now including Extra-Special™ Mega-Colorful Red© Highlight-Magic™® Extended Edition©: (click thumbnail to enlarge)

## Ruby with color, 110 characters

```
puts (1..n=gets.to_i).map{|a|x=(2..n).map{|b|a!=b&&a%b==0? ' ':?_}.join;x.index(' ')??_+x :"\e[41m_#{x}\e[0m"}
```

[image: Extended Edition]

Comment: That looks like it should be a fractal...

Comment: Remove the space within the ternary before the `' '`. It probably messes up your syntax highlighter, but it still works properly. Also, `a%b<1`

Comment: `*''` will work the same as join, and you can check for `a<b` instead of `a!=b` since no factor of a is greater than a. There might also be savings from slicing into a two-character string with the result of some math on a and b instead of using a ternary.

Answer (score 5):

## J - 28 char

```
1('_ '{~0==+&|:1&=+|/~)@:+i.
```

Explained by explosion:

```
1(                    )@:+i.  NB. on vector 1..n, do
                   |/~        NB. take the table "column modulo row"
               1&=+           NB. add 1 to column 1
          =                   NB. identity matrix of size 10
            &|:               NB. transpose both tables (now table is row mod col)
           +                  NB. add them
  '_ '{~0=                    NB. space if cell=0 else underscore
```

What it looks like:

```
   1('_ '{~0==+&|:1&=+|/~)@:+i.25
_________________________
_________________________
_________________________
_ _______________________
_________________________
_  ______________________
_________________________
_ _ _____________________
__ ______________________
_ __ ____________________
_________________________
_   _ ___________________
_________________________
_ ____ __________________
__ _ ____________________
_ _ ___ _________________
_________________________
_  __ __ ________________
_________________________
_ _  ____ _______________
__ ___ __________________
_ ________ ______________
_________________________
_   _ _ ___ _____________
____ ____________________
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>76</s> 71

```python
r=range(1,input()+1)
for i in r:print''.join("_ "[i%j<1<j<i]for j in r)
```

Not sure if it can get any shorter than this... These keywords: `range`, `input` and `print` cost quite a lot.

Comment: You can replace `i>j>1and i%j<1` with `i>j>1>i%j`

Comment: @Sieg: Cool! It's actually my first time exploiting these concatenated comparisons.

Comment: I had written this exact code character-for-character up to var names, including the `i%j<1<j<i` :-P. So maybe it really doesn't get any shorter.

Comment: Actually, I think (not tested) you can do `i%j<1`. It implies `i>=j`.

Comment: @Sieg: Yes, but we need ```i>j```, not ```i>=j``` to avoid blanks on the diagonal.

Comment: Alright. I thought that might be the case, but offered it anyways. I'm too lazy to check the specs.

Answer (score 3):

### APL (28)

```
'_ '[(1+(1≠⊢)∧≠∧0=|⍨)/¨⍳2⍴⎕]
```

Explanation:

- `⍳2⍴⎕`: read a number N and make an N-by-N coordinate matrix
- `(`...`)/¨`: for each pair of coordinates, apply the following function:

  - A cell must have a space if:
  - `0=|⍨`: y `mod` x = 0, and
  - `≠`: x isn't equal to y, and
  - `1≠⊢`: x isn't `1`.
  - `1+`: Add `1` to the resulting bit matrix because APL arrays start at 1.
- `'_ '[`...`]`: replace each `1` with an underscore and `2` with a space.

Comment: Apparently 28 is the magic golfing number here.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl,   <s>69</s>   61

Updated version (thanks, *Dennis*!)

```
$n=<>;for$i(1..$n){say"_".join"",map{$i%$_|$i==$_?_:$"}2..$n}
```

Original version:

```
$n=<>;for$i(1..$n){say"_".join("",map{$i%$_||$i==$_?"_":" "}(2..$n))}
```

Comment: 1. Neither `join` nor `2..$n` need parentheses. 2. With the `-n` switch, you can use `$_` instead of `$n`. 3. `_` is a valid bareword, so it doesn't need quotes. 4. You can use `$"` instead of `" "`. 5. You can use `|`  instead of `||`.

Comment: @Dennis — Thanks! I applied a few of those. I didn't do the `-n` thing because I wanted to keep it a self-contained program and not have to say `$^N=1`. The use of `_` as a bareword worked in the case of `$i==_` but didn't work in the case of `$i%_` because the parser thought `%_` was a hash.

Comment: 1. You can keep it self-contained with a shebang (`#!/bin/perl -n` is usually counted as 1 byte), but that's obviously up to you. I have no idea what `$^N=1` does... 2. `$i==_` won't work properly; it will test if `$i == "_"`. What I meant is using `_` instead of `"_"`, i.e., `say _` and `$i==$_?_:$"`.

Comment: @Dennis — ohhhh crap, you're right. The edit I made introduced a diagonal line through the matrix. Shame on me for not catching that. Fixed. I see what you mean about `_` = `"_"` now. Unfortunately, it works in the latter case but gives me an error next to the `say` because it seems to think it's a filehandle.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 27 bytes

```
q~:I,{__I?'_*S+I*I<'_t}%zN*
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

This approach achieves the same byte count as my other answer, but I thought it was worth posting anyway. Instead of marking proper multiples in every row, it does exactly what the specification says.

#### How it works

```
q~:I                         " Read an integer I from STDIN.                              ";
    ,{                }%     " For each J ∊ {1,...,I}:                                    ";
          '_*S+              " Push J - 1 underscores followed by a space.                ";
               I*I<          " Repeat the pattern to complete I characters.               ";
       _I?                   " For the first row, replace all spaces with underscores.    ";
      _            '_t       " Replace the Jth character by an underscore.                ";
                        zN*  " Transpose rows and columns; separate with linefeeds.       ";
```

#### Example run

```
$ cjam prime-lines.cjam <<< 10; echo
__________
__________
__________
_ ________
__________
_  _______
__________
_ _ ______
__ _______
_ __ _____
$ cjam prime-lines.cjam <<< 100 | md5sum # no trailing newline
83c7b974e1510f482322456a9dbb461f  -
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 143

C is obviously not the right choice of language for this. But for completeness, here's one possible way to do it in C. Works for values of *n* up to 1048575. Reads *n* from standard input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){int n,i=0,j;scanf("%d",&n);char x[1<<20];x[n+1]=0;
for(;++i<=n;){for(j=0;++j<=n;)x[j]=i%j|i==j|j==1?95:32;puts(x+1);}}
```

It is very fast, however.

- Runtime for *n*=1,000,000 (which produces a 1,000,000,000,000-element grid) is approximately 55 minutes on my system.
- Runtime for *n*=1000 (which produes a 1,000,000-element grid) is less than 1/100 second.

Comment: 1. The include is not needed for some compilers (e.g., GCC), so you can remove it. 2. Global variables initialize to 0 and default to `int`, so you can use `char x[1<<20];n,i,j;main...`. 3. `for(scanf("%d",&n);i++<n;)` saves two bytes over `scanf("%d",&n);for(;++i<=n;)`.